# Choose my own points instead of corner points in implementing optical flow in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, opticalflow

The current algorithm uses goodFeaturestoTrack to select corner points but I want to choose my own points. Secondly, I want to save the data as to which pixels has that point moved to. How would I go about solving these two problems? The code I am currently using is :-

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')

# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
# throw every other corners below quality level. Sort rest in descending order. Pick greatest, throw rest in min and pick N greatest
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 1,      # how many pts. to locate
                       qualityLevel = 0.3,  # b/w 0 & 1, min. quality below which everyone is rejected
                       minDistance = 7,     # min eucledian distance b/w corners detected
                       blockSize = 7 )      # 

# Parameters for lucas kanade optical flow
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),   # size of the search window at each pyramid level
                  maxLevel = 2,       #  0, pyramids are not used (single level), if set to 1, two levels are used, and so on
                  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))
                  # Criteria : Termination criteria for iterative search algorithm.
                  # after maxcount { Criteria_Count } : no. of max iterations.
                  # or after { Criteria Epsilon } : search window moves by less than this epsilon


# Create some random color for the pt. chosen
color = np.random.randint(0,255,(1,3))

# Take first frame and find corners in it

ret, old_frame = cap.read()     #read frame
old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  #convert to grayscale

p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)   #use goodFeaturesToTrack to find the location of the good corner.

#cvPoint pl = new cvPoint(2,3)


# Create a mask image for drawing purposes filed with zeros
mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)

while(1):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # calculate optical flow
    # err kind of gives us the correlation error(matching error)

    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

    # Select good points
    good_new = p1[st==1]
    good_old = p0[st==1]

    # draw the tracks
    for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
        a,b = new.ravel()
        c,d = old.ravel()
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
    img = cv2.add(frame,mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
#
#    # Now update the previous frame and previous points
    old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
    p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)
#
## release and destroy all windows.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.release()
```

Comment: So, actually I printed good_new which I guess gives me the pixels as to where that point is moving. Whether I am correct or wrong, please do tell.

Comment: This is correct according to the documentation here (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#goodfeaturestotrack). Also, I appreciate you continue working on the question even after you ask it. I believe your solution is just to change the goodFeaturesToTrack() function. Just make sure the new function returns the locations of lots of points. I'll write up some example code in a few hours, when I can.

Answer (score 2):

Just as Mark Miller mentioned, You can use any feature vector as input points.
[cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=calcopticalflowpyrlk#cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK) will use them to find on the new image new locations of those features by comparing patches of pixels around given coordinates.

To save the new ones You need to catch the returned values of [cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=calcopticalflowpyrlk#cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK)

A little bit about other features:
[cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=goodfeaturestotrack#goodfeaturestotrack) (Shi - Thomasi or Harris corners) are used because the two perpendicular edges are very easy to find which gives lots of features, so even if some of them get occluded You don't end up with nothing. More advanced features like ORB have a lot more information in their descriptors that can be used to link the feature on different images than two parameters aquired in Shi - Thomasi or Harris corners, and it would be a bit of waste to use them with simple Lucas - Kanade algorithm.

Comment: Apparently in my case, I want to track a sticker on a kid's forehead. Since, the kid moves his head in all directions, template matching doesn't suit my purpose very well (although I am working with that for now). But LK algorithm is very good in tracking such points. So, it would be lovely if I could locate it using LK algorithm.

Comment: You could also try some feature matching with orientation invariant features. That is a whole new level of complication. [Here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/what-are-some-free-alternatives-to-sift-surf-that-can-be-used-in-commercial-app) are some hints for it.

You may have some problems if the mentioned kid moves his head too quickly or the camera is too slow. LK is supposed to work for small translations of tracked points.